# Why am I getting "Method not allowed" 405 exception while attempting post request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my C# solution, I am sending Invoice model from MVC project to API project. But from some reason I keep getting an exception 405 - "Method not allowed". I tried modyfing web.configs, enabling cors in program.cs, adding different attributes to the controller endpoint but none of that worked. When I try to send request with postman to https://localhost:7175/api/Invoice, it works, but it doesnt work when I access it through a MVC controller method.

Here I am accessing the API endpoint, (the success status code is always false):

```
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> Download(Invoice? invoice)
    {
        string apiUrl = "https://localhost:7175/api/Invoice/Post";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var content = new StringContent(invoice.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, content);
             response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var table = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataTable>(data);

            }


        }
        MemoryStream stream = genPdf.GeneratePdf(invoice);
        return File(stream, mimeType, fileName);

    }
```

Here is the controller endpoint from the API project(I only receive the invoice model here when using postman):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public MemoryStream Post([FromBody] Invoice invoice)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = genPdf.GeneratePdf(invoice);
        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: You know that you have a different URL in your code than what you said you use in Postman? `https://localhost:7175/api/Invoice` vs `https://localhost:7175/api/Invoice/Post`.

Comment: Yea I know, but when I try to call https://localhost:7175/api/Invoice in the MVC, I get  "Bad request" exception. I think it has smth to do with how postman interprets requests.

Comment: @jenlee123 try PostAsync()

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved my own question. I was passing diferent data type than was expected to the `PostAsJsonAsync()`. So I just passed the invoice model as it is without coverting it to json explicitly and it works.